# What pairing function coincides with the Gödel pairing on the natural numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Gödel's pairing function on ordinals is defined in this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112079/what-is-g%C3%B6dels-pairing-function-on-ordinals). We may compare it with Cantor's pairing function
$$
p(m,n)=\frac{(m+n)(m+n+1)}{2}+n
$$
But these two pairing functions don't coincide on the natural numbers. For example, $p(1,1)=4$, while the ordertype of the initial segment determined by $(1,1)$ in the canonical ordering of ordinals is $3$: $(0,0)\prec(1,0)\prec(0,1)\prec(1,1)$.

So here is the question: is there a pairing function on the natural numbers which agrees with Gödel's pairing function (restricted to the naturals)?

Comment: Well, "Godel's pairing function restricted to the naturals" (or more smoothly, Godel's definition with 'ordinal' replaced with 'natural number') is obviously a definition of such a pairing function. Presumably you want something different, though?

Comment: @NoahSchweber yes that's right. The context of this question is that I read someone's remark that the Cantor pairing and the Godel pairing coincide on the natural numbers. I wonder if this is an error on their part or they have something different in mind

Answer (score 2):

The inverse of the Cantor pairing function follows this path, where $(0,0)$ is the top left point:
[image: Follows each diagonal from lower left to upper right]

In contrast, the inverse of Gödel's function does this:

[image: Jagged path that fills each upper right square before moving to the border points of the next larger square]

Either Cantor invented many paths for reasons unknown, or your source just assumed they were the same without checking.

Noah Schweber is correct (of course). Gödel's pairing function *is* a pairing function on the natural numbers. It just also extends beyond them. Once you get the basic idea of these functions, it is easy to come up with new ones. Just pick some path through all the lattice points and invert it. For example, this path provides another pairing function:

[image: Path completing each upper right square before moving to the border of the next, using only vertical and horizontal lines]